# Display images one by one when user clicks next in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have created a **django** app where user uploads multiple pdf files and it converts to png and displays the images. I am using **ModelForms** for this purpose. The upload and the convert part is working fine but how do I display the Images **sequentially**?

What I want is to display one image and when the **user clicks next, the next image should be displayed**. Below is my app code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class UserUploadModel(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'file_uploads/%d%m%Y')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from app1.forms import UserUploadForm
from app1.models import UserUploadModel
from app1.convert import convert_file
from app1.transfer import move_dir
import os
from project1 import settings

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save()
            f.user = request.user
            f.save()
          
            ff = request.FILES.getlist('file')
            f_list = []

            for i in ff:
                file_instance = UserUploadModel(file = i)
                file_instance.save()
                f_list.append(file_instance.file.path)
            
            [convert_file(j) for j in f_list]

            src_dir = os.getcwd()
            dest_dir = os.path.join(src_dir, 'media/converted_files')            
            move_dir(src_dir, dest_dir, '*.png')
            
            return redirect('app1-display')
    else:
        form = UserUploadForm()
    return render(request, 'app1/home.html', {'form' : form})


def display(request):
    return render(request, 'app1/display.html')
```

**home.html**

```
{%extends "app1/base.html"%}
{%block content%}

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {%csrf_token%}
      {{form.as_p}}
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

{%endblock content%}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display all user's image in your template and then use javascript to hide and show images :

**app1/display.html**

```
{% extends "app1/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    {% for image in request.user.useruploadmodel_set.all %}
         <image src={{ image.url }} style="width: 100%{% if not forloop.first %}; display: none{% endif %}" />
    {% endfor %}
    <button id="nextBtn">Next</button

    <script>
        $(() => {
            $("#nextBtn").click(() => {
               $('image:visible').hide().next().show()
            })
        })
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

I've used jquery because I'm more used to it but that could be done with another framework or vanilla JS.

*Why not using a JS carousel library ?*

Comment: Actually I do not know JavaScript or related frameworks so I was wondering if it could be done using Python, html and css? ANd if not then which JS beginner friendly framework should I use?

Comment: If you want, you can do it in Python with Django, I suggest you to use pagination (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view-function) and set the number of object per page to 1. It would work for your use case.

Comment: Then if you want to use Javascript, I really like Vue.js but it can take some time to understand, and even use it along side Django, so it's really up to you !